# how to get org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference in Junit using mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

In my unit class I have following line of code

```
@Reference private ConfigService configService;
```

and this is being used in this class at many places, but when it comes to testing I dont have any way to set this for testing purpose as there are no getters and setters for this property. Please let me know how can I get this using Mockito

Answer (score 0):

Private field value can be set with reflection without Mockito:

```
    Field field = YoursClass.class.getDeclaredField("configService");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(YoursClassInstance, value);
```