# unit test OSGi service which has Reference to another service

Tags: java, junit, osgi, mockito

I have the following service method that I'm doing Junit test. The SUT class has @Reference to the ResourceResolverFactory service. When I initiate the SUT class, the resourceResolverFactory is always null, which cause throwing NullPointerException when execute the 1st line in the try block: 
resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);

```
@Reference
ResourceResolverFactory resourceResolverFactory;    

@Override
public PropertyStatusInfo getPropertyStatusInfo(String hotelCode,
        String brandCode) {
    LOGGER.info( "Class : " + this.getClass().getName() 
               + " : Method : getPropertyStatusInfo() : [ENTER]");
    LOGGER.debug( "Input Parameters : Hotel Code - "
                + hotelCode + " BrandCode - " + brandCode);
    ResourceResolver resourceResolver;
    Session session = null;    
    try {
        resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.
                           getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
        ...
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Mike, can you provide a bit more details about the test setup (eg., test classes in same project, same package, different project/folder//bundle/fragment; are you using Bnd, Maven, Tycho, Gradle, etc.)? It would allow giving better recommendations for your specific setup.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an instance of the factory is not being injected in your test code.
You can set the `resourceResolverFactory` field to some value, `value`, using reflection:

```
Field field = SUT.class.getDeclaredField("resourceResolverFactory");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(instanceOfSutClass, value);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976626/3895897

Answer (score 0):

As your field is not private you can access it from the same package. So simply put your unit test in the same package as the class under test and you can do:

```
sut = new SUT();    
sut.resourceResolverFactory = myFactory;
... = sut.getPropertyStatusInfo(...);
```

Of course you should still make sure your test is separated from your code under test physically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mock `ResourceResolverFactory` using mockito, or any other mock librairies, and inject it into you tested bean using `@before` of JUnit.

Answer (score -1):

you can use below code as well:

```
import junitx.util.PrivateAccessor;

PrivateAccessor.setField(<Source class>, <variable name>, <variable value>);
```

> Example: Below code injects the mock Externalizer in the LinkTransformerFactory class.

```
@Mock Externalizer externalizer;

LinkTransformerFactory linkTransformerFactory = new LinkTransformerFactory();
PrivateAccessor.setField(linkTransformerFactory, "externalizer", externalizer);
```

> LinkTransformerFactory class

```
@Component(immediate = true, service = TransformerFactory.class,
property = "pipeline.type=mylinktransformer")

@Designate(ocd = LinkTransformerConfig.class) public class LinkTransformerFactory
    implements TransformerFactory { 

  @Reference private Externalizer externalizer;
}
```